ETL Error: Receipt Process Fails to Fetch Data Despite Successful Reruns - Need Insights
I've been experiencing issues with my ETL for the past few months consistently. Our ETL is scheduled to run every 12 AM. I've noticed in one of our tables,
[logs]
[4/2/2024 12:14:14 AM][QLICKSENSE-1][Administrator][10.10.175.101] - receipt: Start : 240401
[4/2/2024 12:14:40 AM][QLICKSENSE-1][Administrator][10.10.175.101] - receipt: Error : 0 rows
Based on these logs, it appears that there's an error with the 'receipt' process, and no data is being fetched. However, during reruns or manual reprocessing, it completes successfully.
Does anyone have any insights regarding this?"

is it possible that at the time when the process is ran the receipt is just empty and by the time when is manually ran the data is already avaialble?

I was thinking the same thing; however, it shouldn't be an error. It should still be marked as finished, similar to this:

[8/22/2023 12:00:07 AM][QLICKSENSE-1][Administrator][10.10.175.101] - receipt: Start : 230822
[8/22/2023 12:00:20 AM][QLICKSENSE-1][Administrator][10.10.175.101] - receipt: Finish : 0 rows

Not related to the SQL language, so I removed that tag. Perhaps you want to add dbms tag instead?

Case closed. Already fixed. Thank you

Out of curiosity. What was the issue?

it has something to do with other data, just like what you said, when the receipt is processing, there's specific data that is still empty.
